# Threading Daemon = True, but using launcher thread as mainthread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working with python 3.6 trying to build a set of sub threads that die when the father dies, without the father being the main thread.

Here mi question:

Im needing to kill a set of threads when the function from which I fired them end.
I currently do that by launching all using daemon  = True and when I finish the main thread all the sons die.
But now I need that functionality from a secondary thread. That is, all children die when the secondary thread end.
Need it whitout doing manual coding. No flag or something like that because the functions ar already write.
I try using ThreadPoolExecutor but do not achieve anything :(

Here  a litle example:

Thank a lot!!!

```
import time
import threading

class FooHilo:

    def print_while(self):
        a = 0
        while True:
            print('im still alive')
            time.sleep(1)

    def main_control(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_while)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        b = 0
        while b < 5:
            b += 1
            print(b)
            time.sleep(1)
        print('Exit... wishing that the thread print_while also end... ')

    def start(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.main_control)
        t.daemon = False
        t.start()


foo = FooHilo()
foo.start()

while True:
    a = input('Input anything:')
    break

print('END...')
```

Comment: I'm not a Python expert. I could be wrong, but I think you misunderstand what "daemon" means.  Daemon threads are not killed when the main thread terminates: They are killed when the _last non-daemon thread_ terminates. The main thread is a non-daemon thread, but whether or not it is the last one to terminate is entirely up to you.

Comment: If you need thread A to kill itself when thread B dies, then you should have thread B set a flag before it dies, and have thread A periodically check the flag.